# Multithreading in Tcl

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I am trying to compute a value and then send the value to the desired thread procedure

I wrote the following code :

```
package require Thread
proc test1 {} {
  set a "Hello How are you?"
  thread::send -async $threadID [list UpdateValue $a]
}

proc test2 {} {
  test1
  set threadID [thread::create {
      proc UpdateValue { a } {
         puts $a
      }
  }
}
```

The code is not working

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with the code. Firstly, variables are not shared between procedures by default. Secondly, you're trying to use the thread before creating it (particularly, before knowing what the target thread ID is). Thirdly, you've got some syntactic problems (a missing `]` in `test2`). Fourthly, you need to tell the receiving thread to wait for incoming messages with `thread::wait` (at the end of the initialisation script) or the thread finishes its script and decides to terminate because it has nothing else to do.

Try the following:

```
package require Thread
proc test1 {} {
    upvar 1 threadID tid
    set a "Hello How are you?"
    thread::send -async $tid [list UpdateValue $a]
}
proc test2 {} {
    set threadID [thread::create {
        proc UpdateValue { a } {
            puts $a
        }
        thread::wait
    }]
    test1
}
```

Comment: Well, you also need to _call the procedure_ but I thought that was obvious. You know, run `test2`. It worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: Depends if `stdout` is shared... And wish (at least on windows) does some crazy stuff with channels.